# Using grep in execl with file descriptor

Tags: c, grep, exec, file-descriptor, unistd.h

I'm trying to do the following:

```
 execl("/bin/grep","grep","print",fd,NULL);
```

where fd is a file descriptor.
So basically this should grep for "print" in the file pointed to by fd.
It doesn't seem to work although I get no compile errors/warnings.
It works when I give a filename such as `"Something.txt"` instead of the `fd`

Can someone tell me why this isn't working? (I know that execl takes only `const char  arg*` but as I said no compile errors/warnings).

Comment: `execl` is a variadic function, so no checking is done on the arguments -- you can pass pretty much anything without it giving an error or warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- You're seducing `execl` into using a small integer as a pointer
- You're expecting `grep` to understand file descriptors

If I understand your question correctly, right before you `exec`, you should redirect the descriptor into `STDIN_FILENO`. Something like:

```
dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
execl("/bin/grep", "grep", "print", NULL);
```

This should work because `grep` analyzes its stdin when no input files are provided.

Comment: I don't get the "You're seducing execl into using a small integer as a pointer" Part. And yes I was wondering if grep would understand file descriptors.

Comment: Well, you said it yourself. *I know that execl takes only const char arg**. So it has no choice than to think the 4 or 5 you're passing is a valid pointer. Which it's not.

Comment: `execl` takes `char *`s, not `int`s.  So he's saying you're passing an `int` where a `char *` is expected (by passing `fd` as the third argument to `execl`.

Comment: Also grep only seems to read only from a file according to the man page. (A quick test `grep pattern < "This is pattern"` also seems to support this) So how will re-directing the the required text to the stdin help grep read it?
(I apologize in advance for any technical errors I might have made here, I'm still learning)

Comment: My bad again. It *does* work on stdin. Sorry and Thanks for the help!